# nginx wget download fails (timeout)

Tags: nginx

I have generated a 10GB file using fallocate. Now when trying to download that file using

```
wget -O /dev/null example.com/10gb.bin
```

it stops at ~72% and says "Connection closed at byte X". Retrying.
error.log doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting variable `proxy_max_temp_file_size` helped us.

Basically this is due to *buffering* on Nginx, which defaults to 1GB size. Anything more than that needs to be requested again.

Answer (score 0):

Since the download started, I suppose the access log won't be of any use either (basically showing a 200 answer). You still may want to check it, just in case something interesting pops up, even if I doubt it.

So. It does not seem to be a server error...

Have you got a look at exchanged packets? Those might help telling you if the server requested that close or if it is your client that disconnected.

In the latter: client error maybe?
It might be something as simple as disk/partition full... :o)